# embedXcode not getting to work

Tags: xcode, arduino, arduino-ide

Using Xcode-v7.1.1, embedXcode+, ArduinoMAC-v1.6.6,

I can't get **embedXcode** to work with any of the boards !

The installation of embedXcode and embedXcode+ was done according to the following [LINK](http://embedxcode.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/1000046704-embedxcode-installation-video)...

The board I intend to use is the "NodeMCU 0.9 ESP-12" as chosen in the create-new-project menu (as seen in middle-image below):

The error crops up by running "Build" (not the "All"-Target):

[image]

The error that I get is "**nodemcu board is unknown**" (see image at bottom)

Can anybody help me with this ? Highly appreciated !!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My case was solved by moving Arduino.app directly to /Applications folder.
I have multiple Arduino.app under i.e. /Applications/1.6.6/ or /Applications/1.7.4 ...etc. then the build process could not find the board.txt file in the Arduino.app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried with your setting (board=NodeMCU 0.9 ESP-12) and build successful. Only the other thing I can think of is your Arduino.app was renamed as "ArduinoMAC-V1.6.6", as indicated above? Also check what HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS shows in the Build setting.

Comment: Hm, somehow it still does not work.... I would really like to be able to choose directly the correct Adafruit HUZZAH ESP8266 board. But EmbedXcode does not list that under the board-choices when creating a project. I added the ESP8266-HUZZAH library to Arduino as described under arduino.cc but again, the board does not take part of the board-choice ! Any idea on what board one would have to chose instead ?

Comment: I don't know this will help but another trial at my side was also successful.
Choose "ESP8266" for board and create a project. Before build, change the build settings 
  BOARD_TAG=huzzah
  BOARD_TAG1=huzzah.menu.FlashSize=4M1M
  BOARD_TAG2=huzzah.menu.CpuFrequency=80
  (or actual your board spec).
There is board.txt file in ~/Library/Arudino/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.0.0/. 
I found settings for huzzah board in that file.

Hope this helps.